# Unit Testing Sqlite Membership Provider in MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, model-view-controller, nunit, membership

I've created an MVC application and I've set up [Roger Martin's sqlite Providers](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SQLite-Providers.aspx) in place of the default Providers.  I'm curious about how I would go about unit testing these.

Below is a stripped down method that has many validations, only one of which is still present.  Among other things, I want to write tests that ensures one can't register if the username has been taken, and can register if the username is free (and other validations pass), etc.

I can see how unit tests could determine success or failure, but not failure for a specific reason, unless I check the output MembershipCreateStatus parameter but I'm not sure if there is a better way.  Further, what I need to give for object providerUserKey?  Any insight would be very helpful.

```
  public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
  {
   //some validations, and then:

   MembershipUser u = GetUser(username, false);
   if (u == null)
   {
    ///register user
           status = MembershipCreateStatus.Success;
           return GetUser(username, false);
   }
   else
   {
    status = MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName;
   }

   return null;
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying unit test the code in the SQLite Membership provider or in your controller?

Comment: For now, the SQLite Membership Provider.  I want to make sure that account registration is denied for a specific and valid reason.  I haven't started writing the controller yet but I see no issue with writing tests for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `out MembershipCreateStatus status` output variable to determine the reason of failure (duplicte username, invalid password, duplicate email, etc).

The value will be one of the following:

```
MembershipCreateStatus.Success
MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName
MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail
MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword
MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail
MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidAnswer
MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidQuestion
MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidUserName
MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError 
MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected
```